# Windows Server 2016 Disk Issue When Pausing Updates

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I decided to pause updates Via group policy for all Windows servers to prevent updates from getting installed while on vacation. Normally, updates get installed as soon as they are released. When I set the policy `Computer configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Windows Update for Business > Select when Quality Updates are Received\[Checked] Pause Quality Updates` Something strange happened. Disk read write activity went way up causing Hyper-v replica to be about 2gb per 5 minutes cycle. Since I keep 24 hours of replicas, this caused the receiving server to run out of disk space triggering a shutdown of hosted machines. this occurred on about 3 servers so far.

I know there are several ways to temporarily disable Windows updates but any idea why selecting Pause Updates via GPO would cause this issue? When I returned the policy back to normal, the problem was resolved after a gpupdate.

Comment: Are there lots of `.evtx` files in `c:\windows\temp` by any chance?